# How to validate html page using Selenium

Tags: java, validation, selenium, w3c-validation

I want to check if site is OK, and uses html5
Normally I can use service like https://validator.w3.org and http://www.css-validator.org, where I can paste URL and check it, but site I need to test is not accessible from outside.

I've tried to save page as html and then upload it to this service but I have errors like:
File not found: import file://localhost/css/jquery.fileupload.css: Operation not permitted

Can I do it localy ? I'm using selenium in Eclipse using java, so I want to use this tool.
Can some one direct me into good solution?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Do you have access to the API? Can you post the file via curl, instead of uploading it?

https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html